# Storing date and time in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I have a form in which I ask users for a starting date and time, sometimes a time isn't required so I seperated the fields into `start_date` and `start_time` where `start_date` is of type **date** and `start_time`was a **varchar** but I feel that a **time** field is more appropriate.

So, what is the best way to store these fields in terms of flexibility and the ability to concatenate in the future?

Or is it a more standard practise to have a single field and combine the two values given by the user?

Comment: for date and time use `type` `DATETIME` store date time as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Is there any benefit to storing them separately?

Comment: If the time is optional, then I think you should store it separately - otherwise, how would you distinguish between a record that doesn’t have a time, and one that has it coincidentally say `00:00:00` in the time portion of a full datetime? You can NULL your separate time column, but you could not make “part” of a datetime value NULL.

Comment: @04fs That should be the answer.

Comment: Under what circumstances is time not required?

Answer (score 1):

> and start_timewas a varchar but I feel that a time field is more appropriate.

Yes, definitively. As soon as you need to perform some sort of “time operation” on the value at any point, like say add or subtract a certain amount of minutes, VARCHAR would become a hassle.

> Or is it a more standard practise to have a single field and combine the two values given by the user?

Since the time is optional, I think you should store it separately - otherwise, how would you distinguish between a record that doesn’t *have* a time, and one that has it coincidentally say `00:00:00` in the time portion of a full datetime? You can NULL your separate time column, but you could not make “part” of a datetime value NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to enter date and time in mysql database.

```
<?php
$db=mysqi_connect("localhost","username","password","database_name");
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
mysqli_query($db,"insert into table(Date_Today)values(''$date')");
?>
```